# Help identifying frame brand/model

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, identify-this-bike

My friend gave me this frame and the old paint job was covered with spray paint so I decided to paint, strip and run it raw.

I need help with identifying the frame. The pictures provided show the dropouts, the headtube, welded parts and the seatstays.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  An overall picture that shows the geometry of the frame would help too.

Comment: Oh definitely, i forgot Haha. Thanks!